# Splitting output of select box (Checkboxlist) in Umbraco using Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am trying to output the checked values of a checkBoxList on a view but keep getting an error when using the .split() method.

That's my loop with nothing separating the items:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("robots"))
```

{@item}

But the output is as follow:

**itemitem**

And I would like it to be:

**item, item**

I have tried adding the .split() method but keep getting the error...

```
CS0117: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Split'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also added some  field to it but I dont see this as a decent solution, and it adds a coma at the end of the whole thing which is not ideal.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("robots")){@item<text>,</text>}
```

Comment: I'm thinking that you need to get the property value as a single string first, then split it, and then go through the values in a for loop?

Comment: Good shout.. I'll give this a go and see how it works.Will update once I tried.